# Sequelize dialect dependency on msnodesqlv8

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, odbc

We are using sequelize package to connect to mssql server. Our backend code is in javascript.

We have a working code like below:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  logging:log,
  dialect:'mssql',
  dialectModulePath: 'msnodesqlv8/lib/sequelize'
  dialectOptions:{
   connectionString: process.env.connectionString,
   encrypt: false
  },
  operatorAliases: false
})
```

Below is the format of connectionString we are using in above snippet:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; Server=<<Servername>>;Database=<<Database>>;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

And in package.json I can see below 3 packages:

```
"msnodesqlv8":"^2.4.7",
"sequelize":"^4.41.2",
"sequelize-msnodesqlv8":"^0.2.6-beta.8"
```

In official doc of sequelize, I can see

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect:'mssql',
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  // SQLite only
  storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite'
});
```

There is no mention about `msnodesqlv8`. Right now connection is working fine. But I was just trying to understand if sequelize uses tedious under the hood in order to have appropriate drivers so that connection to DB can be made. Then what is the use of `msnodesqlv8`?

In `msnodesqlv8` official docs I can see it has some enhanced security features.

What I am trying to achieve by understanding this?

I want to remove the dependency of my code from `msnodesqlv8` and snippet provided in official document of sequelize for mssql is not working for me.

Reason for removing dependency of `msnodesqlv8`?

We are migrating code to linux and msnodesqlv8 is compatible with linux which has dependency on msodbcsql17 driver which needs to be installed separately.

Comment: Ok. So after going through many articles what I understood is, Tedious being pure javascript is not good with integrated security. Hence here packages like `msnodesqlv8` comes into picture, which provides drivers to ensure proper working of `sequelize`. But it also seems like msnodesqlv8 has dependency on `msodbcsql17` which needs to be installed separately. Anyone who has some idea about this would like to correct me if I am wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

After going to the pain of switching to the msnodesqlv8 driver today, I felt like I should comment on this... unfortunately my rep isn't high enough to comment so you get an answer instead :)

1. You're correct, many people seem to be using the msnodesqlv8 driver for the integrated security aspects.
2. I does have a dependency on msodbcsql17 (be sure not to try msodbcsql18).  And this dependency is a pain to get in place.  Word of warning.. trying to use it in a debian based docker image results in segfaults.  We switched to alpine based and the segfaults cleared up.
3. What I haven't seen mentioned anywhere is the significant performance improvement you get from using msnodesqlv8.  Small example, we have a simple query (takes .3 seconds to execute and another .3 to return 29000 <1kb rows using the JDBC driver) that would take 58 seconds using tedious.  That was using tedious directly (not through sequelize or mssql for node).  Almost all of that time was it reading the result stream.  Switching to msnodesqlv8 reduced the time to under 2 seconds.

Summary: Pain to install.  Much better performance for some workloads.